# Lógica de un login

Tags: angularjs, nodejs, express, login, autenticación

Saludos estoy tratando de crear un login funcional y simple con AngularJS, NodeJS, Express y MySQL vale la pena decir que en los tres últimos tengo poca experiencia.

Pero necesito un poco de ayuda con la lógica del login, hasta el momento el supuesto usuario introduce sus datos, son enviados al servidor donde se comprueban con los almacenados con la base de datos, esta devuelve los datos pertinentes del usuario.

Hasta este punto todo bien, pero no se exactamente como manejar si un usuario está logeado o no, se puede hacer con el session storage pero al introducir una variable sería fácilmente manipulable por alguien con suficientes conocimientos.

Además, nada le impediría a alguien que sepa las rutas de la pagina saltarse la pagina del login.

Necesito que alguien me diga como enfocar la lógica de esto, no busco código especifico simplemente la lógica para poder seguir tirando para adelante. Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como veo que estas usando AngularJs te recomendaría para el login la librería Satellizer, esto para el lado del cliente, en el servidor como estas usando NodeJs, busca la librería para NodeJs de JWT, el login funciona de la siguiente forma:

1. Desde el cliente se ingresan los datos de acceso ejemplo. email y password
2. El cliente con ayuda de Satellizer hace un llamado tipo POST con $auth.login(user), donde user son los datos de acceso.
3. El servidor verifica los datos de accesos, si son correctos desde el servidor creas un JSON Web Token
4. El cliente recibe este token y lo ingresa en el localstorage

ya después lo que queda es con el mismo Satellizer verificar que el usuario este logueado, además ten presente que apenas se cree el token, satellizer enviara en cada petición al servidor el token, así solo queda que crees un middleware con node para que verifiques este token.

te paso los links de interés, en el sitio de satellizer hay varios ejemplos inclusive uno con NodeJs.

[Repositorio de Satellizer en GitHub](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer)

[Un ejemplo de un blog del uso de Satellizer + NodeJS](https://carlosazaustre.es/blog/autenticacion-con-token-en-angularjs/)

Te recomiendo mucho esas librerías te ahorraran mucho trabajo